# Linking errors with libusb, wxWidgets, and MSVC 2013

Tags: visual-c++, wxwidgets, libusb, libusb-1.0

I'm working on a utility for a USB device which uses wxWidgets in C++ to display a GUI. I'm trying to link libusb (which I precompiled with MSVC 2013) to the project. I made a simple window based off of the "minimal" example.

Everything is fine until I get this link error:

Error   11  error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
Error   9   error LNK2005: _GUID_NULL already defined in uuid.lib(cguid_i.obj)

How do I fix this? What is _GUID_NULL?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are defining any global variable in multiple header files causing recursive header references. But we need some more details about your definitions and headers. So kindly add more details for investigation :)